# Same variable name for element and collection in ForEach

Tags: powershell

Why does Powershell let you use the same variable name for an element and collection in a foreach?

How does the foreach implementation know which variable to refer to in the following code?:

```
$x = @('a','b','c','d')
foreach ($x in $x)
{
    Write-Debug $x -Debug
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter which variable it uses.  You should never do this unless you truly hate the next person to work on this code.

Comment: That doesn't answer either of the two questions.

Comment: The first step in a foreach loop is to create an enumerator (called $foreach) from the pipeline object (the $x after "in"). Then enumerate values in the collection (through $foreach.MoveNext()) and assign each value in turn to your foreach $x variable.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave I wasn't trying to answer your question (note this is a comment, not an answer). I was pointing out to the person who reads this in six months that if you ever see code that does this, it is a bug, not a feature.

Comment: It works for the same reason you can use a variable on both sides of an assignment operation. The variable on the right side of the `in` keyword is expanded only once before the iteration starts, then the value of the variable is replaced with each element of the list during the iteration as it's being (ab)used as the loop variable.